# Configure Ssl in Apache With Virtualhost

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-rewrite

I am trying to configure apache for Ssl connection, but when i try to access the website with https is not possible.

Here is the VirtualHost for my website:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\www.example.com"
ServerName www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\www.example.com"
ServerName example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I have omit #  before this line in c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf 
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

i have add this lines in c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.con

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect /xampp folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} xampp
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /phpMyAdmin folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} phpmyadmin
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /security folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} security
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect /webalizer folder to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} webalizer
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have added an SSLRequireSSL directive inside of each directory of the following files:

```
Config File: c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
c:\xampp\phpmyadmin
c:\xampp\htdocs\xampp
c:\xampp\webalizer
c:\xampp\security\htdocs
Config File: c:\xampp\webdav
c:\xampp\webdav
```

The error logs when i restart apache:

```
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.739140 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.742070 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.947148 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.948125 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.949101 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:25.077031 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please change the  *ServerName*  directive to match the certificate Common Name as apache logs are suggesting?
To verify if the Common Name you used in your certificate matches the Server Name please run

```
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject
```

If this does not work could you please use a fully qualified domain name, like *mydomain.dev*. To make it work add the domain in your hosts file to resolve with the loopback IP 127.0.0.1 - this is similar to step 1 in my article https://www.bizmate.biz/articles-mainmenu-2/18-little-it-tricks/48-ssl-virtualhost-apache2-xampp

This is how to change your hosts file. https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Also for the sake to establish if SSL is configured correctly could you please just focus on it and disable mod_rewrite for a moment. Infact if it does not work pls use the steps in my article to the letter and revert any changes you have done so far/start from scratch. Then you can get the mod_rewrite to work later once your browser and apache are happy with the certificate and the SSL encryption.

Comment: i substituted ServerName with 127.0.0.1 but it doesn't work. Than i added line  127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com at httpd-vhosts.conf file but still nothing.

Comment: the hosts file has nothing to do with apache. IT is a file to force your machine to resolve your domain to that ip. This is how to change your hosts file. https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/
please set it to a very specific domain something like belka.dev and then in your apache vhost (not to be confused with the hosts file) change the server name. 1- disable the ssl vhost and see if apache start, 2 re-enable the ssl vhost and see if it works or if not the error from logs. Pls generate the ssl certs as per article step 3 if not done it that way.

Comment: i did but still nothing. the error logs says: 
 RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
 [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH02292: Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
[Fri Jun 23 10:00:24.947148 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5012:tid 268] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint:

Comment: Did you follow the step 3 in my article for the generation of the certificate? What did you use as Common Name? what do you see if you run?
openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject

Comment: i tried that command and the output is CN=www.mydomain.com, the same server name i have in virtualhost. But i still get in the error log 
[Tue Jun 27 10:38:51.227375 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 2468:tid 268] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: Can you show the logs? if it is still mentioning localhost like in your post then it is not picking up the certificate you are looking at or the vhost is not configured with the right name. In any case I think you should start from scratch as you have added SSLRequireSSL everywhere and you should not have. If you can delete xamp install and start from zero again and only modify required files (dont touch all those files like c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf ... )